# Rails routes for article/234 and article/index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to setup the following urls:

```
/article (article#index)
/articles/1234  ( article#show with id 1234)
/articles/new  (article#new)
```

Can I define this using:

```
resources :article do
  ???
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look very closely at your question, it appears that you want the index to be at `/article` instead of the default Rails REST convention, which is `/articles`

It doesn't make any apparent sense to model your routes that way, but if that is surely what you want to do, then you could add one more route line in addition to the call to `resources`

```
resources :articles
match '/article', :to => 'articles#index'
```

Comment: no that was a type sorry, it is /articles. btw, isn't the rails way to be singular like /article or is it /articles?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just learning rails. I'd suggest generating an `article` scaffold. It will set up a route like so for you:

```
resources :article
```

And you'll get RESTful routes setup for you automagically by rails

```
GET        /articles            index     display a list of all articles
GET        /articles/new        new       return an HTML form for creating a new article
POST       /articles            create    create a new article
GET        /articles/:id        show      display a specific article
GET        /articles/:id/edit   edit      return an HTML form for editing an article
PUT        /articles/:id        update    update a specific article
DELETE     /articles/:id        destroy   delete a specific article
```

You can then dig into this and learn how rails does things.

Here's the official [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want those URLs and nothing else, you should put the following in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :article, :only => [:index, :show, :new]
```

In case you haven't stumbled upon [the official Rails 3 routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), you should definitely take a look at it!